# Crash in overriding `new` and `delete` in OSX 10.8.2

Tags: c++, macos

I have recently started getting crashes in my code where I have had to override the default `new` and `delete`, I'm not entirely sure but it could be after a recent software update.

I'm running Osx 10.8.2 build 12C54 and the following gcc :

i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1

Here's the stack trace of my crash.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8f2a4212 in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x00007fff8fdecaf4 in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x00007fff8fe30dce in abort ()
#3  0x00007fff8fe04959 in free ()
#4  0x00000001009cd947 in foundation::aligned_free ()
#5  0x00000001009e5322 in (anonymous namespace)::delete_impl ()
#6  0x00000001009e53e8 in operator delete[] ()
#7  0x00007fff87316ecc in TPropertyStream::SetLength ()
#8  0x00007fff87286099 in TPropertyStream::WriteData ()
#9  0x00007fff87286037 in TPropertyStream::Write ()
#10 0x00007fff87285ce7 in IAStoreStream::MaybeFlushBuffer ()
#11 0x00007fff87285641 in BuddyStorage::Commit ()
#12 0x00007fff87316c4c in TPropertyInfo::FlushChanges ()
#13 0x00007fff873169af in TPropertyInfo::FlushChanges ()
#14 0x00007fff8729ac47 in THFSPlusPropertyStore::FlushChanges ()
#15 0x00007fff872dc5e4 in TFSVolumeInfo::FlushVolumes ()
#16 0x00007fff872b087a in TNode::HandleFlushVolumes ()
#17 0x00007fff872684d3 in TNode::HandleNodeRequest ()
#18 0x00007fff872db4e7 in __block_global_1 ()
#19 0x00007fff87268040 in ExceptionSafeBlock ()
#20 0x00007fff87267fe1 in __PostNodeTaskRequest_block_invoke_0 ()
#21 0x00007fff8e074f01 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#22 0x00007fff8e0710b6 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#23 0x00007fff8e07247f in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#24 0x00007fff8e0722f1 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#25 0x00007fff8e0721c3 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#26 0x00007fff8fdedcab in _pthread_wqthread ()
#27 0x00007fff8fdd8171 in start_wqthread ()
```

Has anybody experienced similar problems?

Comment: How can we tell you what's wrong without looking at your overridden operators?

Comment: Show us at least the overloaded operators `new` and `delete`, please. And the piece of code, from which it is called wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Apologies for the vague question, I'm doing my best to find bugs in code that I dont fully understand, please see Francois' extra details below

Answer (score 1):

Jon was kind enough to post our problem on SO. I am the author of the code in question. We have been shipping code on Mac OS X for years without problems. We are also shipping on Windows (32-bit and 64-bit) and many flavors of Linux. Troubles started only recently on Mac OS X.

Basically our app is made of a couple binaries using a couple shared libraries (.dylib on Mac OS X). All variants of `new` and `delete` are overloaded in one of these shared libraries. They are not supposed to be exported and used by the other shared libraries and binaries, and indeed they aren't on Windows. For reference the overloaded operators are [here](https://github.com/jupiter-jazz/appleseed/blob/master/src/appleseed/main/allocator.cpp#L472).

I'm not sure exactly what is happening, however **the callstack above seems to indicate that some Mac OS X code is freeing up memory using our own `delete` operator, and I'm not completely sure that memory was allocated with our overload of `new`, or if it was allocated with another memory subsystem entirely.**

In any case it really shouldn't use our operators. Ideally the overloaded `new` and `delete` would be hidden to the outside like it is the case on Windows (since shared library symbols are hidden by default on that platform).

The code was built on Mac OS X 10.8.2 using gcc 4.2.1 (686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)). Amongst other things we are using prebuilt binaries of Qt 4.8.2 (the latest stable version at the time of writing). We recently switched to a newer version of Qt on Mac OS X, could that be related to the problem? Could it be that the prebuilt Qt binaries are somewhat incompatible with our code? (We're linking dynamically against Qt so it shouldn't be a problem.)

Hope that's enough details to get the conversation started.

Franz

Comment: You seem to have at least some debug/tracking capabilities coded into your allocator. I assume your codebase is rather large and auditing the codepath in question isn't feasible. My first step would be to augment that so that you keep track of blocks allocated by the allocator, who allocated them (i.e. in what function), as well as who is freeing them. This should go a long way towards helping you catch the bug and provide a good framework for tracking down future issues.

Comment: Sure, we have (simple but fully functional) built-in tools to track memory allocations/deallocations and memory leaks. Tracking down the (de)allocations would be interesting, thanks for the suggestion. Of note is the fact that the app has been running fine for many years, we're looking into what changes in the setup (besides upgrades to Mac OS X and to Qt) could have triggered the problem.

Comment: Running `nm libappleseed.dylib` and looking at the (massive) output indicates that `operator new(unsigned long)` and co. are indeed exported. We will try to hide them using the `-unexported_symbols_list ld` option and see if that solves the issue. Still no idea why this breaks only now though.

Comment: Did your version of gcc change, perhaps? As for the issue being Qt, I don't know see how, but stranger things have happened I guess. I wish I could offer a complete solution, but this sort of issue can be tricky to track down, especially for someone with no familiarity with the full codebase.

Comment: We will have to check if the recent upgrade from Mac OS X 10.7 to 10.8 led to an upgrade of gcc. At first it doesn't appear so (IIRC we were already using gcc 4.2.1). Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions so far, highly appreciated.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune You may have been switched from gcc to llvm-gcc.

Comment: we have indeed beed building from llvm-gcc for a while now with no problems

Comment: So we are able to confirm that the root of the problem seems to be that memory is allocated with one subsystem and deallocated with another (ours, actually). Often it would crash while releasing memory in the (inline) constructor of std::locale: http://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc_40/gcc_40-5494/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/locale_classes.h (the delete[] call at the end of the file). This memory seems to be allocated elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> In any case it really shouldn't use our operators. Ideally the overloaded new and delete would be hidden to the outside like it is the case on Windows (since shared library symbols are hidden by default on that platform).

Generally visibility in shared libraries on Unix corresponds to external linkage in C++. That is, if an item has external linkage in the C++ language then it is externally visible in shared libraries. GCC's visibility attribute is even documented as modifying linkage. (or it used to be, I don't see that now...)

Furthermore, load time linking can be considered as part of phase 9 in C++'s phases of translation, and so load time linking of shared objects and dylibs on unix platforms generally behaves like static linking rather than dynamic linking. That is, if you replace `operator new` in a translation unit that gets linked at load time then the load time linker will resolve this for all the static and load time linked translation units, just as if you had replaced `operator new` in one of the statically linked translation units.

It's perfectly legal and well defined in C++ to delete memory allocated in one translation unit that was allocated in another translation unit. Since by default load time linking is  the same in this respect as static linking there's plenty of code out there that does this even between load-time linked translation units. Again, this is legal and well defined so long as it's properly understood that load time linking is part of phase 9 and is therefore bound by the C++ specification.

Of course this does not apply to fully dynamic linking using routines such as `dlopen()` as that happens after phase 9 is over and the program has started running. The behavior of such programs is implementation defined (or undefined in C++03) and so not bound by the requirement that resources allocated in one TU can be deallocated in a different one.

---

The problem is that Windows doesn't behave this way. Windows' load time linking seems to behaves more like dynamic linking, and whether a symbol or type is exported has no relation to C++ external visibility. In fact, as far as I'm aware, it's not even possible to export `::operator new` in a Windows dll.

I'm not convinced Windows' load time linking is really conforming, but a lot of code has to deal with it. It's no problem for code that only has to run in one or the other environment, but it's more tricky for code that's supposed to run on both Windows and other implementations. The most frequent way is to simply not overload `operator new` or `operator delete`. You can write your allocation and deallocation functions with another name, perhaps as a C++ Allocator class. Another option, if you only need to handle your own user defined types, is to define member `operator new/delete` to deal with those types.